# Не срабатывает jQuery скрипт

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице есть выпадающий список

```
  <select name="Role" id="Role">
            <option value="2">
                Brand Manager</option>
            <option value="3">
                Brand Managers Chief</option>
            <option value="4">
                CEO</option>
        </select>
```

есть див, в который в зависимости от выбранного пункта списка должен выводиться текст `<div id="txt"></div>`
Пишу такой скрипт

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("select#Role").change(function() {
                $("select#Role option:selected").each(function() {
                    if ($(this).value == "2") {
                    } else {
                        $("div#txt").text("test");
                    }
                });
            }).trigger('change');
        });
    </script>
```

Но почему-то значение выводится каждый раз независимо от того, какой пункт выбран.
Как это можно поправить?

Comment: id="Role" не дублируется ещё где-нибудь на этой-же странице ?

Comment: @eicto нет, не дублируется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Какой-то перебор у вас. Может сделать попроще?

```
$("select#Role").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "2") {
            $("div#txt").text("2");
        } else {
            $("div#txt").text("test");
        }
});
```